# How do I get the desired amount via regex from the stated text lines

Tags: c#, regex

how do I get the amount part from the following lines:

```
ADCOL UPGDE AMNT – 1212
ADCOL UPGDE AMNT – 123
ADCOL UPGDE AMNT – 144
```

the lines will always start with the following:

```
ADCOL UPGDE AMNT –
```

and then the amount added I want to fetch just the amount or say digit.

So far I tried `ADCOL UPGDE AMNT – ([0-9])`
the problem is it matches anything after the digits also so if I had:

```
ADCOL UPGDE AMNT – 144somewords
```

it will catch that also, I want to stop where the amount ends

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what issues are you facing with your current approach?

Comment: `\d+` or `[0-9]+` should help if that is the only numbers expected. That `+` tells it to match every consecutive digits together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Int32 number = 
        Int32
        .Parse(
            Regex
            .Match(
                input: "ADCOL UPGDE AMNT – 1212",
                pattern: @"ADCOL UPGDE AMNT – (\d+)")
            .Groups[1]
            .Value);
```